# Can an iPad somehow connect the iPad Camera Connector AND be plugged into power simultaneously?

Tags: ipad

Can an iPad somehow connect the iPad Camera Connector AND be plugged into power simultaneously?

I need to use the USB port AND have the iPad connected to a power source.  Possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not with Apple's own kit, but you can find various adapters on places like ebay which do what you want. My friend has one similar to [this](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/New-5-in-1-Multifunctional-iPad-iPod-Camera-Charger-Connection-Kit-Stock-in-UK-/320937343006?pt=UK_iPad_Tablet_Accessories&hash=item4ab95b381e#ht_3051wt_1180) which appears to work fine (on iOS 5.1.1 at least).